# Socket.io server "Error-handling middleware" equivalent of express?

Tags: socket.io

```
const app = require('express')();
const native_server = require('http').createServer(app);
const socketio = require("socket.io")
const ws_server = socketio(native_server)

native_server.on("error", err=> {
  console.log(`Error caught in the native server`)
  console.log(err)
});

ws_server.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log(error)
    console.log("Caught error in the socket error handler")
  })
  socket.on("test", (req, cb) => {
    console.log("On test")
    // cb("Test complete")
    throw Error("hi")
  })
})

native_server.listen(3001)

const io = require("socket.io-client")
const cli = io("http://localhost:3001")
cli.emit("test")
```

When throwing an error in the socket event handler, it just terminates server and my terminal returns the prompt. The `native_server.on("error", ...)` seems to not work because it uses `EventEmitter` but it's something I want

I want to handle the error like how you can do that in express using

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { ... handle unhandled error ... })
```

Is there any 'general error handler' for socketio?

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone I think my title was misleading. I'm looking for something equivalent of express error handling middleware. Edited title.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have error handling middleware for socket.io as in express, but you can still do that a little bit differently, just by wrapping the callback in your own error handler, like:

```js
const errorHandler = (handler) => {
  const handleError = (err) => {
    console.error("please handle me", err);
  };

  return (...args) => {
    try {
      const ret = handler.apply(this, args);
      if (ret && typeof ret.catch === "function") {
        // async handler
        ret.catch(handleError);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // sync handler
      handleError(e);
    }
  };
};

// server or client side
socket.on("hello", errorHandler(() => {
  throw new Error("let's panic");
}));
```

Example is taken from the official [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#error-handling)